# array elements separated by ',',and str_replace();?

Tags: php

I have an source data separated by `,` but some cases in the its elements contains `,`

```
$A = Array
  (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ",123, abc , company , Inc., 3043, 200, USD",// [123], [abc] , [company , Inc.], [3043], [200], [USD]
            [1] => ",456, def , company,Inc., 3043, 200, USD"
        )

  )
```

By could not change the data source.( company , Inc., is always `fixed array orders` )

```
foreach ($A as $key=>$value){

  foreach($value as $k=>$v){
       $line  =  str_replace(',', ';', $v);
       $row = explode(',', $line);
      list($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f) = $row;

  }
}
```

EDIT:

RULE:

yes , the order of `company , Inc` always fixed and the number of `,` always 6

Comment: Unless you know of a specific rule when an item could contain `,`, there's no way of safely getting the elements.

Comment: Wait a minute, the only place extra `,` are on the "third" column ?

Comment: @IEnAK are you 100% sure there will **always**, ***really always*** be names like "company, inc" and not names like "acme corp" without the `,` as well? Also, why is there a `,` at the beginning of each row?

Comment: Also, what is the code you are showing supposed to do? it seems unrelated to the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = explode(',', trim($string, ','));
while (count($array) > 6) {
  $array[3] = $array[3] . ',' . $array[4];
  unset($array[4]);
  $array = array_merge($array);
}
```

Just a short description: We merge the 3rd and 4th element together, as long as there are more than 6 elements.

Another a little bit more straight forward solution:

```
$array = explode(',', trim($string, ','));
$result = array_slice($array, 0, 2);
$result[] = implode(',', array_slice($array, 2, - 3));
$result = array_merge($result, array_slice($array, -3));
```

Comment: +1 for offering a different solution, I dislike using unset/while for something this trivial.

Comment: @IEnAk: I see, its not the string. However, see it as a placeholder :)

Comment: @Khez: I like loops ^^ And `unset()` is only here, because its required ;) However, I thought about it and found a solution, that squash the merge-part into one step and so (as a side effect ;)) avoids the loop. Dont see a problem with `while`, but this solution feels cleaner anyway

Comment: Uuu array_slice/array_merge o.o interesting solution. I like for/while just felt this particular situation didn't need it. :D

Answer (score 1):

Change the source data to contain quotes around the values, e.g. change it to

```
 [0] => '"123", "abc" , "company , Inc.", "3043", "200", "USD"'
```

Then use [`str_getcsv`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

Comment: yes the source is already string,what you want me to changed here?

Comment: He want you to put quotes around the items. Another solution is to change every separator (`,`) to something uncommon, for example `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Made you a simple function that does it. The only reason I create $foo,$bar,$baz is so you can easily use foreach and keep the order.

```
function parse($str){
    $parts=explode(',',$str,4);
    $result=array($parts[1],$parts[2]);
    $parts=explode(',',$parts[3]);
    $foo=array_pop($parts);
    $bar=array_pop($parts);
    $baz=array_pop($parts);
    $result[2]=implode(',',$parts);
    $result[3]=$baz;
    $result[4]=$bar;
    $result[5]=$foo;
    return $result;
}
```